# Unpacking list with ternary

Tags: python

```
test = [1,2]
one, two = test[:]
print(one)
print(two)
one, two = test[:] if len(test)==2 else test[0], test[0]
print(one)
print(two)
```

Output:

```
1, 2, [1, 2], 1
```

Why does unpacking the list fail when using `if` as a ternary operator?

Comment: `one, two = test[:] if len(test)==2 else (test[0], test[0])` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is precedence:

```py
test[:] if len(test)==2 else test[0], test[0]
```

is parsed as

```py
(test[:] if len(test)==2 else test[0]), test[0]
```

Which is not what you want. Use manual parentheses:

```py
test[:] if len(test)==2 else (test[0], test[0])
```